# Adding dimensions leads to inflated pageview metric

Tags: python, google-analytics-api

I'm using the [Google Analytics API Client Library for Python](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/) to query pageviews data from the [Google Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/). I want to get pageviews by pagePath, date, and country. If I make a call like this (using only the pagePath and date dimensions):

```
service.data().ga().get(
        ids='ga:' + PROFILE_ID,
        start_date=from_date,
        end_date=to_date,
        metrics='ga:pageviews',
        dimensions='ga:pagePath,ga:date',
        filters='ga:pagePath=@docid=363746',
        max_results=MAX_RESULTS,
        start_index=start_ind).execute()
```

I get results that match what I see on the web interface:

> [u'/irj/portal/anonymous/kbproblem?docid=363746&productcd=axwbas&problemnbr=680&fromkbresultsscreen=t',
>   u'20140101', u'1']
>   [u'/irj/portal/anonymous/solndtls?docid=363746&searchid=363746&aparno=qo77072&product=axwbas&os=nt&release=11.1&number=0000093&type=&actionid=5&pos=n/a',
>   u'20140101', u'1']

Note that there is only one view of each of these two pages on April 1. Now, if I add in the country dimension like this:

```
service.data().ga().get(
        ids='ga:' + PROFILE_ID,
        start_date=from_date,
        end_date=to_date,
        metrics='ga:pageviews',
        dimensions='ga:pagePath,ga:date,ga:country',
        filters='ga:pagePath=@docid=363746',
        max_results=MAX_RESULTS,
        start_index=start_ind).execute()
```

I get results that have the same two pages, but with two pageviews each:

> [u'/irj/portal/anonymous/kbproblem?docid=363746&productcd=axwbas&problemnbr=680&fromkbresultsscreen=t',
>   u'20140101', u'China', u'2']
>   [u'/irj/portal/anonymous/solndtls?docid=363746&searchid=363746&aparno=qo77072&product=axwbas&os=nt&release=11.1&number=0000093&type=&actionid=5&pos=n/a',
>   u'20140101', u'China', u'2']

If I remove the filter, I do not get any pages viewed only once. All page view counts are >= 2. In the web interface, I see many pages that were only viewed once. Why is this? Adding a dimension shouldn't inflate pageviews, should it?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved. I haven't changed anything on my side, but it seems Google fixed whatever the bug was because the results are now as expected.